Tailwind CSS does not apply styling to Vite React App
I've never used Tailwind and thought I'd give it a try for a new project I'm working on. I quite literally copy/pasted the instructions provided in their docs here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite and none of the styles are being applied.
The only thing I've done to change the vite app is remove the default App.css and remove the default styling inside the index.css. However, I correctly updated all the imports so this shouldn't be causing any issue. Can someone help me diagnose this issue?
package.json:
{
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}

postcss.config.js:
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}

tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

index.css:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

App.tsx:
import "./index.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


Browser caching issue ? Did you check the console ? Does the npm run dev  command works without error ? I did exactly what you did (following the tailwind/vite tutorial, adding the tailwind.config.js config, deleting app.css, adding tailwind base config in index.css, changing app.jsx) and everything works on my side
